# XSL string parsing and getting value with a bid oddity

Tags: xml, xslt

Been fighting with this as an XML beginner, and the result I have is what I have to work with.  My XML being returned is the following:

```
<Response .... />
  <Metric ... />
     <stuff .... />
     <Stuff  .... Sname="On"  Tag="Parameters: (@SID: dftdr.23423.s1.RT, @STYPE: X)" />
```

Well I am trying to get my output with select to say Parameters and the sid value there.  So It would display in this example, Parameters dtfdr.23423.s1.RT  .  I got one half of it done by doing this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(/Response/Metric/Stuff[@Sname='On'][1]/@Tag, 1, 9)"/>
```

But I can't think of a way to parse the SID out easily with a dynamic value getting its length.  I can get the start position but I can't seem to figure out and easy IndexOf concept for the "," or if there's a better way to do this.

This is the base XML it's the cards that are dealt, so I can't do anything to change it.

Is there an easier way I could write out that buried @SID value?

Much thanks for your help, hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: Look at combining substring-before() and substring-after().

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, you could look at tokenize() or replace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression to parse out the `SID`

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(/Response/Metric/Stuff[@Sname='On'][1]/@Tag, '@SID: '), ',')"/>
```

Comment: This has worked nicely thanks for your help, a bit cryptic but looks like it's working.